# Is signrawtransactionwithkey secure?

Tags: signrawtransaction

is the node API signrawtransactionwithkey (as documented here https://developer.bitcoin.org/reference/rpc/index.html) secure or recommended? This API takes a private key, so i want to understand how that private key is handled by the node. Thanks!